# Problems enrolling Android client in WSO2 EMM

Tags: android, wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I want to use WSO2's Enterprise Mobility Manager to manage a fairly large amount of Android-tablets (100+). For now we don't have any iOS devices, so at this moment the focus is on Android. I have already setup the EMM Server and I am able to acces the device manager at https://myurl.com:9443/emm . I have also downloaded the WSO2 Android agent app from the [WSO2 git here](https://github.com/wso2/MDM-Android-Agent). After fixing some SSL-related errors I am able to succesfully make a connection to the server.

However, when I use the agent app to enroll a device (an Acer IconiaTab with Android 4.0.3) my LogCat in Eclipse shows various logging messages (at verbose level):

```
11-10 14:55:29.050: D/WSO2MDM(4573): Attempt #1 to register
11-10 14:55:29.190: D/dalvikvm(4573): GC_CONCURRENT freed 368K, 12% free 7903K/8903K, paused 2ms+9ms
11-10 14:55:29.320: D/dalvikvm(4573): GC_CONCURRENT freed 710K, 14% free 7705K/8903K, paused 3ms+4ms
11-10 14:55:29.410: V/WSO2MDM(4573): Posting '{regid=APA...wrg}' to https://myurl.com:9443/mdm/api/devices/isregistered
11-10 14:55:29.410: V/WSO2MDM(4573): Posting 'regid=...wrg' to devices/isregistered
11-10 14:55:29.420: D/dalvikvm(4573): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 13% free 7807K/8903K, paused 3ms+4ms
11-10 14:55:30.150: V/GCMRegistrar(4573): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2014-11-17 14:55:30.152
11-10 14:55:30.160: V/Check Reg Success(4573): From Demo Server: successfully added device!
11-10 14:55:30.160: V/Register State(4573):  
11-10 14:55:30.160: V/Register State(4573):  
11-10 14:55:30.160: V/Register State(4573):     
11-10 14:55:30.160: V/Register State(4573):
```

which is followed by many more of these Register State messages, each including a line of html code from the management console html page (the response from the API.) Everything seems to be ok, but when I go back to the EMM Console and refresh the page, no enrolled devices are shown (at https://myurl.com:9443/emm/devices/management). The emm server console window also doesn't show any sign of a new enrollment, but it also doesn't show any errors (at debug-level).

Where do I have to look for the source of my problem, and more important: How do I solve it?

Of course myurl.com is not used anywhere in my code, and I have shortened the regid from the log above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the newer version of the Android Agent, found on the [WSO2-dev Git account here](https://github.com/wso2-dev/emm-agent-android). Devices are now succesfully registered to the WSO2 EMM server. Also, this new version of the Android agent is structured way better and has cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Im facing the same problem, but cant find the mentione .APK file anymore
Another reported problem: https://cmsdk.com/android/wso2-unable-to-enroll-android-device.html

It does look like constatly changing company :(

Thanks for any help